# Calling the same function both in application and in linked dynamic lib

Tags: c++, linux

I wrote a C++ class containing some static methods and I use it to build a library as dynamic library under Linux.
Then I compiled an application that use the same class and it links also the dynamic library previously compiled. In this way the class is used either in my application either in dynamic library.
When the application runs it causes a segmentation fault when a function of dynamic library calls a static method of the class: looking at the stack trace using gdb it seems to be a memory corruption because the error is very strange.
I suspect the problem is the call to the static function because his address showed in gdb stack trace is the address of symbol in executable binary and not in the library .so file. (I checked the addresses using nm tool)
The application calls the "wrong" version of the function.
The application can see two identical copies of functions: one symbol in application binary and one symbol (the same symbol) in dynamic library file.
My question are:

1. How can I distinguish the call of functions in application and in the library project? (considering that the class with static functions is the same source for both projects)
2. Why when I compile the application, the linker does not report an error for duplicated symbols?

Thanks

### Update with more details

- Trying to compile the application without compiling the class used by the library works perfectly.
- The application needs to compile the class because afterwards it will be called but now it does **NOT** use it. Only the linked library uses it.
- The static methods of the class calls a C function (declared using *extern "C"*). I tried to define a namespace in the library but without success. The static function called now is the correct one because the symbol has a different name using the namespace, but the function internally calls a *global* C method that has no namespace so the segmentation fault happens equally because it calls the *wrong* C function.
- I don't understand why it crashes if the application calls the wrong function (the own version instead of the library version). The functions are identical and it is called only by the library (the application does not call it). There should be no difference on what function is called.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  It is rarely appropriate to tag both, and this case is not one of the rare exceptions.  Since there's no uncertainty about which you actually mean, I've edited the tags.

Comment: @Stefano, why don't you use the function  from the class in the dynamic library if you are actually linking it to your executable? Or the class in the library is supposed to be private?

Comment: Have you tried quick fixes, like commenting out the class (in the application), or giving the shared library its own namespace?

Comment: @Alienpenguin because the linked library does not expose that function as public. That static function is private into the linked library.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes I tried to comment out the class usage in the application and it works without any segmentation fault. In this way there is only one symbol of that function in the linked library and none in the application. Using a namespace into the library seems to be a good idea

Comment: Very hard to answer a question like this for sure. I have an idea to try though. Make sure the application *and* the library and both compiled with PIC (position independent code). Libraries require it and executables may use it, but that option will definitely change how functions are compiled. A PIC library calling a non-PIC function will blow up.